# Jenkins pipeline shared library - fails to get match when using groovy .contains (git ls-remote)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

Currently having problems with trying to match results from git ls-remote. Currently testing for the existence of a repo, however during testing I have 6 repo's to test with one not existing. However when running the code, git ls-remote reports that the none existent repo is not found, but the function is still treated as true.

I've tried quite a few things including setting the pattern and the output of git ls-remote to lower case. Aswell as trimming both results. Previously I didn't have "|| true" on the end of the script but when it didn't find a repo it failed before reaching the if statement.

```
def is_repository(repository_name)
{
    sshagent(['03876f99-2a9d-4980-b543-f8b478d4f1ec'])
    {
        String repository = sh( script: "git ls-remote git@bitbucket.org:<company_name>/${repository_name}.git || true", returnStdout: true)
        println(repository)
        String pattern = 'and the repository exists.'
        if(repository.contains(pattern))
        {
            println("Repository: " + repository_name + " not found")
            return false
        }
        else
        {
            println("Repository: " + repository_name + " found")
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Expected output is it to return false if it finds "not found" in the output of git ls-remote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is a simple one. When using jenkins `sh()` call, you can define `returnStdout` but not `Stderror` as `Stderror` is just printed to log and not passed to the variable.